# How do I correctly allocate more memory in this custom stack implementation?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, data-structures, stack

I am trying to make it so that my Stack doubles in size every time the size is exceeded. I need to create a new stack to hold the old stack, but have double the size. The old stack needs to be deleted. The code below keeps giving me errors

"Stack(17854,0x7fff77cd0300) malloc: *** error for object 0x1001054b0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug"

Also, the random numbers being generated are the same every time I run my program. HELP!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int DEFAULT_SIZE = 100;

template< class T >
class Stack {
public:
    Stack( int = 10 );  // default constructor (stack size 10)
    // destructor
    ~Stack() {
            delete [] stackPtr;
    }

    bool push( const T& );
    bool pop( T& );
    int pop();

    // determine whether Stack is empty
    bool isEmpty() const {
            return top == -1;
    }

    // determine whether Stack is full
    bool isFull() const  {
            return top == size - 1;
    }

private:
    int size;     // # of elements in the stack
    int top;      // location of the top element
    T *stackPtr;  // pointer to the stack
};

// constructor
template< class T >
Stack< T >::Stack( int s ) {
    size = s > 0 ? s : 10;
    top = -1;  // Stack initially empty
    stackPtr = new T[ size ]; // allocate memory for elements
}

template< class T >
bool Stack< T >::push( const T &pushValue ) {
    if ( !isFull() ) {
        stackPtr[ ++top ] = pushValue;
        return true;
    }

    T *newPtr = new T[size*2];
    newPtr = stackPtr;
    delete [] stackPtr;
    return true;
}

template< class T >
bool Stack< T >::pop( T &popValue ) {
    if ( !isEmpty() ) {
        popValue = stackPtr[ top-- ];  // remove item from Stack
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

template <class T>
int Stack< T >::pop() {
    return stackPtr[--size];
}

int main() {
    Stack<int> s;
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i < DEFAULT_SIZE; i++) {
        s.push( rand() % 100 +1 );
    }

    for (i=0; i < DEFAULT_SIZE; i++) {
        cout << s.pop() << " , ";
        if (i % 20 == 0) {
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding the first question, you'll have a better time with the problem if you make a [mcve]. There's lots of stuff in the current code that's irrelevant to the problem. Regarding the second question, read some documentation for `rand`.

Comment: You are flubbing the "reallocate when full" code rather badly, two bugs there.  Does std::stack sound attractive yet?  Hang in there, you'll get it eventually.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at this code, which is from your `push` implementation (it's the part where you allocate more memory):

```
1: T *newPtr = new T[size*2];
2: newPtr = stackPtr;
3: delete [] stackPtr;
4: return true;
```

Visually, here's what's happening. Before line 1, things look like this:

```
 +----------+       +-----+-----+-----+-----+
 | stackPtr | ----> | 137 | 271 | 281 | 284 |
 +----------+       +-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

After executing line 1, things look like this:

```
 +----------+       +-----+-----+-----+-----+
 | stackPtr | ----> | 137 | 271 | 281 | 284 |
 +----------+       +-----+-----+-----+-----+
 +----------+       +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
 |  newPtr  | ----> |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |
 +----------+       +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

After executing line 2, things look like this:

```
 +----------+       +-----+-----+-----+-----+
 | stackPtr | --+-> | 137 | 271 | 281 | 284 |
 +----------+   |   +-----+-----+-----+-----+
 +----------+   |   +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
 |  newPtr  | --+   |  s  |  o  |     |  a  |  l  |  o  |  n  |  e  |
 +----------+       +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Oops. You just orphaned a bunch of memory.

After executing line 3, things look like this:

```
 +----------+        
 | stackPtr | --+->    kablooie! deleted memory.
 +----------+   |
 +----------+   |
 |  newPtr  | --+
 +----------+
```

Notice that when you're done, you've ended up with orphaned memory (all the ?'s) and your `stackPtr` variable now points to dead memory. Oops.

To fix this, you'll need to make a few changes. First, when you wrote

```
newPtr = stackPtr;
```

my sense is that you intended to copy over all the elements from the old array to the new one. Unfortunately, as illustrated above, what you wrote doesn't do what you think it does. To fix this, you'll need to explicitly move over the elements one at a time. Consider using a `for` loop to do this - read from `stackPtr` one element at a time and write to the corresponding entry in `newPtr`.

Second, you'll need to change `stackPtr` so that, after you've blown up the memory that was previously allocated, you have it point to the newly-allocated memory. One way to do this would be to write

```
stackPtr = newPtr;
```

after you've freed the memory for `stackPtr`.

There's one other issue here. Notice that you never actually updated `size` after allocating the new array. This means that while you will get a brand-new array to work with, you won't actually remember how big it is. Therefore, after you've done everything else, make sure that you update `size` so that it's twice as big as before.

There may be other issues in the code, but I suspect that this will help get you started. Some things to remember:

1. It never hurts to draw pictures when working with pointers.
2. Be careful not to confuse "assign a pointer" with "copy elements of an array."
3. Remember to do all the necessary bookkeeping.

Good luck!

Comment: One more bug is that the code doesn't do the push in case there is not enough memory.

Answer (score 2):

```
T *newPtr = new T[size*2];
newPtr = stackPtr;
delete [] stackPtr;
return true;
```

This ends with `stackPtr` pointing to it's now-deleted original memory.  You also never actually move the content of the old memory to the new memory.  It should be something like:

```
T* newPtr = new T[size*2];
std::move(stackPtr, stackPtr + size, newPtr);
delete[] stackPtr;
stackPtr = newPtr;
```

---

Regarding `rand` returning the same thing every time; you never seed the random generator.  You need to call `srand` at the beginning of the program, before you ever call `rand`.

Answer (score 0):

This code is clearly wrong:

```
T *newPtr = new T[size*2];
newPtr = stackPtr;
delete [] stackPtr;
```

You allocate a new pointer, then immediately discard it, then delete it. So the newly allocated memory is leaked, and `stackPtr` is already freed and invalid. You're also not updating `size` when it changes (well, when it would have been changed, if you weren't leaking memory like a sieve), and you sometimes use `size` when you probably meant `top`.